# Python scripting in Blender: cannot import pytorch

Tags: python, scripting

I'm using Blender 4.0, and my machine runs Ubuntu 22.04.

Here is my basic problem: I have a python file, call it `rendering.py`, that will set up multiple scenes and render them. I have a second one, call it `learning.py`, that needs to take these renders and do a machine learning task on them. The specific task is irrelevant, but it relies on the python library PyTorch (at the top of the file I write `import torch`). When I run `learning.py` directly, everything works as intended.

The problem arises when I import this module into `rendering.py`. The top of the file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

import bpy
import mathutils
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

# Import my own modules
dir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
if dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(dir)
import scriptutils
import learning
```

If I run this file using Blender's command-line (`blender --background  --python-use-system-env --python rendering.py`), I get the error message "no module named torch".
I know that it's not an issue with the fact that I import the module from somewhere else, first because `scriptutils.py` is imported just fine (it's another module that does some minor tasks and imports its own libraries), and second because the error is still there if I copy-paste all of `learning.py` into `rendering.py`.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Is there some way for me to point Blender directly towards where PyTorch is located?

Thank you!

Comment: i am not sure whether you know, but Blender has its own python installation in it. So it is not the same as it is installed on your computer. So if you include python libraries on your computer, they are not automatically transferred to the python version inside Blender. More information and how to solve it here: https://youtu.be/2zGIERHU2mk?si=RW9vBmJhUX_vG3kM

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, this solved my issue!